# Closing curly braces in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, braces

```
import{Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
        selector: 'pm-app',
        template: `
        <div><h1>
        {{pageTitle}}
        </h1>
            <div>My First Component</div>
         </div>
        `}) 
export class AppComponent{
    pageTitle: string = `My first Angular app`;
```

As you can see, there's a missing curly brace at the end, but in my editor VS Code, I can't type it, says, **code language not suported or defined?**

How to solve it, thanks

Comment: are you clear with your question?

Comment: I am, the problem is, closing curly braces or " } " are AltGr + N on my keyboard, and I can't type it, works fine on other editors, including Visual Studio

Comment: Solved it, went with another language on my keyboard, sadly, but works...

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that you are missing constructor, and your single quote for `My first Angular app` was wrong:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-app',
  template: `<div>
               <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
               <div>My First Component</div>
             </div>`
}) 

export class AppComponent {

  pageTitle: string = 'My first Angular app';

  constructor() { }

}
```